# Is there a way to specialize a function between compile time and run time?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

With `constexpr`, A function can be evaluated at compile time or runtime depending upon the arguments. But usually, the algorithm has to be different between compile time and runtime. Eg. Consider the constexpr version of factorial.

```
constexpr int fact(int n)
{
return (n)?n*fact(n-1):1;
}
```

If `n` happens be at runtime wont the function be inefficient than one forloop? Is there some template magic to determine if the function is being executed at compile time or run time and use different algorithm?

**Update**: 
factorial was just an example. Is all `constexpr` functions be as efficient as they would be if coded without `constexpr` restrictions?
Eg:

```
constexpr int combinations(int n, int k)
{
//Assume all error conditions and edge conditions are taken care with ternary operator ?:
return fact(n)/(fact(k)*fact(n-k);
}
```

If the function is written in runtime, it can benefit from [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Even this was possible, I guess it will be difficult to express the function such that it is both `constexpr` and also as efficient as possible in runtime.

Comment: It doesn't answer you question, but the function will not be inefficient if your compiler optimizes for tail recursion.

Comment: @Eduardo The compiler needs to do more here since the function is *not* tail recursive. Modern compilers *can* optimise this in simple enough cases though (OP’s example would be optimised).

Comment: No, there is no way in the current language to check when a `constexpr` function is being executed - the compiler may decide on a `rand() % 2 == 0` whim whether or not to evaluate the function at compile- or runtime (assuming that the preconditions for it actually being evaluated at compile-time are present).

Comment: @Xeo: well, if the result need be a compile-time constant (template parameter, `static <built-in> const`, ...) then you can ensure the computation is done at compile-time; obviously this does not answer the question though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: you are right; it has to multiply the result by n after the call. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

No, as far as I know you can't detect how the compiler is using the function in a given call, or direct the compiler to use different implementations depending on constness.

But first of all, a `constexpr` function is restricted to a single `return` statement, which means that the compiler can (most often) easily apply tail recursion optimization, turning a recursive call into a loop. Thus, this question is about how to do **premature optimization**, which is not a good idea. Low level optimization is the compiler's job: let it.

Secondly, if you really really want to do the compiler's job then you can just *name the functions*, instead of trying to senselessly cram two different function implementations into a single one. For what purpose would that serve? Only obscurity.

---

For the particular example given,

```
constexpr int fact(int n)
{
    return (n)?n*fact(n-1):1;
}
```

the compiler has to recognize that it can be rewritten as tail-recursive. As I recall from my testing for an earlier SO question about it, even the Visual C++ compiler does that. Although for some inexplicable reason (possibly having to do with the original x86 processor design) it was stumped by use of floating point type: same high level logic, different low level result.

As a slightly less drastic help-the-compiler work effort, after having measured and found that this function is the one that makes your app unacceptably slow, and after having inspected the machine code and found that the compiler fails to recognize the function's tail-recursiveness, you can rewrite it as follows:

```
constexpr int fact( int multiplier, int n )
{
    return (n != 0? fact( multiplier*n, n-1 ) : multiplier);
}

constexpr int fact( int n )
{
    return fact( 1, n );
}
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's dirty hands.

Comment: Unless you have a really relaxed floating-point mode, the floating-point version can't be rewritten automatically, because it changes the semantics of floating-point traps.  The original one can produce an overflow trap after recursion, the almost-equivalent may only trigger it before recursion.  Also, floating-point multiplication isn't commutative/distributive, and the almost-equivalent multiplies `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2` whereas the original multiplies `2*3*4*...n`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: for the ordinary SO reader I think it's best to also mention that for a result that's within the range of integers that can be represented exactly by the floating point type, which is about 51 bits for ordinary 64-bit IEEE 754, the floating point multiplication is exact and commutative (and distributive). anyway, thanks! i didn't think of either possibility that you mention, only about machine code level synchronization of the floating point processing.

Comment: @Alf: Yes, the differences are likely to only affect the last couple bits of the computed precision, which is 80-bits or more on x86 CPUs.  So there should be no change after rounding to double precision.  (In the general case fixed-precision floating-point math is not commutative/distributive at any precision, but a factorial product behaves much better than the general case.  Whether the compiler can deduce that this is a well-behaved case is doubtful.)

Comment: Also, I think the part of this answer that claims that it's senseless to overload a function name is quite ridiculous.

Comment: @BenVoigt: sorry, your statement that I've "claims that it's senseless to overload a function name" is incorrect, just completely fabricated, and you know it. and you're trying to make readers believe it. hence, you're lying. also, your "also" is implying that your claim is an observation about incorrectness/absurdity that comes in addition to some earlier such observation. well it ain't an observation (it's just a misleading claim on your part) and it doesn't come in addition to any earlier observation. and you know also that. hence, also that a lie. sorry about nailing those two lies.

Comment: @Alf: I don't know what else "name the functions, instead of senselessly cram two different function implementations into a single one" can possibly mean other than an overloaded name.  It really means *giving two implementations a shared name is or can be senseless*.   If you didn't mean that "it's senseless to overload a function name" then you really need to rewrite that sentence.  I'm not lying, I'm just taking you literally.  Furthermore, the word "also" simply means "I have another comment/observation in addition to the ones I've already made."  That's not an untruth, let alone a lie.

Comment: Note that I'm carefully trying to avoid using quotation marks to set off phrases which are not quotes, because of your previously expressed displeasure about that, even though that's a perfectly valid and normal use of quotation marks.

Comment: Please note that, unline the first one, I don't want these comments to be a permanent part of the discussion.  I'm hoping to convince you to rewrite part of your answer which would typically be read to mean something entirely different than what you probably meant.  I'm familiar enough with C++ to decipher the useful nugget that's in there, but most people coming along and reading your answer won't be, so it is important to avoid answers that could be understood completely wrongly.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I do not believe that you do not know what "overloaded function name" means (defined by section §13 of C++11), as you indicate. A main reason is that as I recall (your SO description is blank) you're a Microsoft MVP in C++, as am I. And as such you must know at least the basics of C++, and you can't fail to understand that it requires separate functions. And that hence, *overloading* would be an entirely reasonable solution to providing two functions doing the same, also here, with explicit choice in each call. You have failed to convince me that you didn't understand a thing.

Comment: This question also wants two separate functions.  But instead of overloading on parameter types, he wants to overload on evaluation environment (one function/implementation/body for use during compiler evaluation of constants, a different implementation for the compiler to emit runtime instructions for calculations with variable inputs).  The wording in your answer tells him to use two different names any time you have two different function implementations... in other words, as written, your answer forbids overloads.

Comment: All he's asking is that the compiler automatically select which overload is used, based on whether it is precomputing results or generating code for later execution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Updated Question with another example. Will that be optimized too?

Comment: @balki: i don't think a compiler would see how to optimise the particular implementation of nCk that you've shown, because there's essentially two loops involved in combinatorial, two ranges of integers are multiplied. but it's worth checking what the compiler can do. and also note that this implementation is about the most inefficient possible. i think i'd express nCk in terms if nC(k-1). but i haven't thought it through... ;-)